# Saving 16 bit binary data type in C

Tags: c, arrays, types, binary

How do you store a 16 bit binary in an array in C? What data type would I have to make the array? long int, float, char? 
ex. data = {'1001111101110010', '1001101011010101','1000000011010010'}

Comment: I think `long double` doesn't get used nearly enough, so I'd go with `struct bin16 { long double bits[16] ; }` -- and if bits get any bigger, I wouldn't have to change the representation.  (Of course, the other children may laugh, but my mother says I'll grow into it.)

Comment: @gmch: You are kidding, right?

Comment: I was thinking float, but maybe double would be better.  (And, yes, I'm joking too.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within `stdint.h` is the following `typedef`:

> uint16_t

This integer type is exactly 16 bits in width.  You can use it for your needs like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t arr[NUM_ELEMENTS] = {...};
```

Answer (score 2):

The only type I am aware of that can store anything resembling:

***{'1001111101110010', '1001101011010101','1000000011010010'}***

is a char array:

```
char *binaryArray[] = {"1001111101110010", "1001101011010101","1000000011010010"};
```

I am pretty certain that is *not* what you want.

***There are several types that would work to hold*** *an array* of bits (but they are not presented that way);
`unsigned short`,
`short`,
`wchar_t`,
`unsigned __int16`
(et. al.)  all have 16 bits.
***[Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)*** for other data types that would work.

Pick any one that will work, and create an array of ***C bit fields***.  In C this could look like:

```
typedef struct
{
    //type              member name    field width (number of bits in field)
      unsigned short    bits           : 16;
}BIT;    

BIT bit[10];  //array of 10 bit fields, each with capacity for 16 bits
```

***Note:***

An assignment such as:

```
bit[0].bits = 40818;  //0x9F72 //1001111101110010   
bit[1].bits = 39637;  //0x9AD5 //1001101011010101   
bit[2].bits = 32978;  //0x08D2 //1000000011010010
```

Does not look binary, but it is equal.

You can read more about bit fields in ***[this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm)***